# How to create this shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

this is a shadow on car body. how to create this shape in illustrator? please feel free to point my way!

[image]

Comment: Hi @turaj, welcome to GD.SE. It would be helpful if you could explain what you have tried so far and what has and hasn't worked in achieving this effect. At the moment this question would be considered too broad meaning there's either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. I'd recommend visiting the [Help Center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) and consider revising your question so the community can come up with more accurate solutions to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradient fills and gradient meshes are the obvious ways to get the light and shadows illustrated. In some cases the 3D effects (extrude with bevel, revolve) are useful. Those all are extremely well presented in User's Guide and in the tutorials. Here is one more way to choose from:

[image]